# Как загрузить файлы на VDS + дать IP?

Tags: сервер, vps, vds

Купил VDS на бегете, самый простой. Есть сайт (простая верстка). Заказчик попросил разместить у себя на сервере, и выдать ему IP. Он данный IP запишет в A запись домена и данные будут браться с моего сервера.

P.S Выдать домен он не может но и разместить у себя тоже не может.
Раньше с сервером не работал, каким образом мне надо поставить файлы (в какой папке и надо ли создавать папку с названием домена)? Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Видимо заказчик хочет чтобы сайт открывался по IP адресу VDS сервера. В вопросе не указан веб-сервер, а так же язык на котором движок сайта работает (или используются только html страницы?)

Comment: Сервер имеет Ubuntu 18.04

Насчет сайта - это только одна html страница со стилями

Comment: ubuntu - это только ОС. веб-сервер нужно ставить, `apache`, `nginx`, и тд.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev чувак еще не шарит прост. Короч, советую изучать nginx